# Using a two-dimensional array as a function argument in (c++)?

Tags: c++

As you know a multidimensional array must have bounds for all dimensions except the first when we are defining that before main.
I have a 2d matrix and want to use it as an argument of a function. This 2d matrix has a row and a column and I must initialize column...
I know these ways:(and do not want to use the command line for defining the value of column.)

```
//1-using a number
void sample(int array[][5]);
int main(){.....}
```

or

```
//2-using a static parameter
#define x 5
void sample(int array[][x]);
int main(){.....}
```

But non of them is useful 4 me, do u have any other suggestion?

Actually this is my main code:

```
#define colu 7
#define colu_ 7

int compute(char mat1[][colu],int r1,char mat2[][colu_], int r2);
int main(){
.
.
.
int m;
m=compute(mat1,r1,mat2,r2);
cout<<m<<endl;
return 0;}

//****************
int compute(char mat1[][colu],int r1,char mat2[][colu_], int r2){
...
}
//****************
```

I need passing these 2d matrices in "compute" function.

Comment: Can you fill out in more detail what you're trying to accomplish, along with the code to go with it?

Comment: Yes, I will add it to the question just now...

Comment: Don't add tags for unrelated different languages!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use templates to either automatically or directly define the column sizes:

```
template <size_t col1, size_t col2>
int compute(char mat1[][col1], int r1, char mat2[][col2], int r2)
{
    std::cout << "c1: mat 1 is " << r1 << "x" << col1 << "\n";
    std::cout << "c1: mat 2 is " << r2 << "x" << col1 << std::endl;

    return r1;
}
```

If your matrix sizes are known at compile time you can use it just like this:

```
int main() {

    char mat1[1][1] = { { 'a' } };
    char mat2[2][2] = { { 'b', 'c' },{ 'd', 'e'} };
    compute(mat1, 1, mat2, 2);
    compute(mat1, 1, mat2, 1);
    return 0;
}
```

Yet if you need to work with `char**` this implementation is not really useful...

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use parameters you can always use a vector of vector:

```
void sample(vector<vector<int>>& array)
```

And then you can obtain the respective size with:

```
array.size();
array[0].size(); // if at least there is a row
```

Also note that as stated in comments, using a vector of vector isn't the same thing as a Matrix since row could have differnets size.

The other option is to have a single vector and using some math to access specific row col:

```
double matrix::get( size_t x1, size_t y1 )
{
    return m[ x1 * x + y1 ];
}
```

Comment: Remember that this could end up with rows of different sizes - so not necessarily a 2d matrix, so while I'd definitely go for `vector` I'd advocate using just a single vector (size: x * y) wrapped in a simple accessor class

Comment: A bit like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29693700/c-2d-vector-got-error/29694032#29694032) perhaps

Comment: Thank you, yes I know this approach. It will be my last attempt...I prefer to use 2d array instead of converting that to a vector. But thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to use C99, use a VLA.

```
void sample(int rows, int cols, int array[rows][cols]);
```

In C++, use a `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` instead of a 2D array.

```
void sample(std::vector<std::vector<int>> const& array);
```

Comment: I used this: void sample(int rows, int cols, int array[rows][cols]); but receive an error which says: "use of parameter ‘cols’ outside function body
"

Comment: @shirin, it works fine for me using `gcc  -std=c99`. What compiler and compiler options are you using?

Answer (score 1):

If your array dimensions are known at compile time, you can use a template:

```
template<int X, int Y>
void foo(int (&array)[X][Y]) {
    std::cout << X << ' ' << Y << '\n';
    for(const auto& arr : array) {
        for(const auto& i : arr) {
            std::cout << i << ' ';
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}

int main() {
    int asdf[2][5] = {
        { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 },
        { 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 }
    };
    foo(asdf);
}
```

This won't work if you dynamically allocate your array with `new` though.

Comment: Thank you very much, using template idea as you & Simon told is a good point for me :)